# R.layout.activity_noconnection error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently changed my package name using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio)  method. but now when im trying to create a new activity its giving me an error on R.layout.activity_noconnection (on R). then i pressed alt+enter to fix the error it imported "import OldPackageName.R" and that fixed the issue, so that means my old package name is still there in in the program . can someone explain to me whats happening and is there way to completly remove the old package name?
thank you!

image below

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYapZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at you `AndroidManifest.xml`. Under Application you should find a package name. That should be the one used for R.

Answer (score 0):

check package name in build.gradle (Module level) file

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"// Check your package name here
}
```